# RxJs's Take stops the stream unexpected

Tags: rxjs

Why in this given example:

```
of(2, 4, 6)
    .pipe(
        tap(item => console.log(item)),
        map(item => item * 2),
        take(2),
        map(item => item - 3),
        tap(item => console.log(item))
    ).subscribe()
```

Produces the output: `2, 1, 4, 5`.

I would have expected that the output will be of `2, 1, 4, 5, 6`.

The 6 should be coming from the first `tap`, and the take(2) should stop the Stream only upon being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding how Observable chains work. By default, everything in RxJS chains happens synchronously which in this case when `take(2)` receives the second item it'll reemit it as is.

This means that `4` goes down't the chain synchronously and reaches your observer (none in this case since `subscribe()` is empty). But `take(2)` isn't done yet. It was the second item so it completes the chain immediatelly. So the `complete` notification goes down the chain to your observer that triggers its dispose handler that recursively disposes the connections between operators up the chain and marks subscribers as "stopped" so they will [never emit another `next` notifications](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/9a40869c1277112a6325bedc2f3c2537404a512a/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L71). So `6` is never emitted.